# Returning a pointer to the youngest student in a dynamic array

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am currently trying to write some function which will iterate through a dynamic array which holds students records in this format:

Name ID Age

Once this function finds the youngest age, return this as a pointer to the main function and output it.

The problem is the function is of type Student, which is my structure; and is formatted like so:

```
struct Student{
string name;
string id;
int age;
```

};

I am struggling to return the pointer (ptr) and output it to the console, as currently it is outputting (what I think) is the memory location...

Here is my code so far,

Any advice will be very helpful.

The structure:

```
struct Student{
string name;
string id;
int age;
```

};

The function call:

```
cout << "Youngest: " << youngest(student_Dynamic, sizeOf) << endl;
```

And the function:

```
    Student* youngest(Student* s, int size)
{
    int tempAge = 0;
    int youngestAge = 100;
    Student *pt = new Student;

    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        tempAge = (s+i)->age;

        if (tempAge < youngestAge)
        {
            youngestAge = tempAge;
            pt->age = youngestAge;          
        }
    }   
    return pt;  //Here I am trying to return the pointer so that it outputs the youngest age
                //to the console window...

}
```

UPDATE:

This question has now been answered by 'Billy Pilgrim'

Thankyou everyone for the advice!

Comment: Is `s` really the best name to represent your array of `Student` objects? Also, why are you creating a new `Student` object, instead of returning a pointer to the existing `Student` object in the array?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want just the lowest age, why not return an `int` from the `youngest()` method?

Comment: @puelo He wants to return the pointer to the `Student` with the lowest age. But, he's creating a new student record inside the function, so it isn't going to point to the same `Student` even though the values might be the same. This has memory leak written all over it.

Comment: Well it is clear to me, but it will not be clear to others; cheers for the tip. But do you have any advice for me on how to solve the issue in hand? Cheers

Comment: What is your expected console output? You're simply outputting the memory address because that's what is stored in the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the pointer, which is what is being printed.  It should be something like:

```
Student * s = youngest(student_Dynamic, sizeOf);
cout << "Youngest: " << s->name << endl;
```

(Not sure what `sizeOf` is:).

Comment: Ah, this has worked for me! Much thanks! Could you just explain what the Student *s is doing at the start of the function call?  Is it creating a pointer to the function, and s is going toh old whatever value is returned? And sizeOf is the size of my array (so no out of bounds etc...) +1 for this awesome help!

Comment: If you look at the orange ? when writing an answer, you can see more information about formatting code blocks.